# Detectar lectura de Scanner System.in sin presionar enter

Tags: java

Actualmente trabajo con un dispositivo que tiene incorporado un scanner(symbol ls7708) que lee los datos de un codigo de barras y los envia via System.In.

Yo estoy utilizando la libreria Scanner para levantar el input y trabajar con el. El problema esta en que cuando lee los datos del barcode por alguna razon esperar un enter o un salgo de linea o algo parecido para empezar el proceso y yo quiero que se haga automaticamente.

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        text = scanner.nextLine();
```

En resumen, necesito que llegue al nextline sin necesidad de un enter.

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos tendrás  que configurar tu dispositivo para que luego de leer el código de barras de un enter eso se puede con el manual del equipo o consulta en la pagina del fabricante..

Comment: Tenias razon se hacia leyendo un barcode en especifico sobre el lector.